# r for loop with names mutate

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, na

The goal is to replace NAs with 0 values in a set of variables using a loop function. Obviously, this is a super simple loop function, but I have no idea why this is not doing what it should.

two additional preferences, suggestions that use the variable names (as opposed to column numbers) and use dplyr are preferred.

library

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
```

sample data

```
y <- structure(list(pid = c(1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L,1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L), year = 1968:1977, weeks_hd_e = c(3,0, 50, 49, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 49), weeks_wf_e = c(4, 6, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), weeks_hd_u = c(NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0), weeks_hd = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), weeks_wf_u = c(NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA), weeks_wf = c(NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_)), .Names = c("pid", "year", "weeks_hd_e", "weeks_wf_e","weeks_hd_u", "weeks_hd", "weeks_wf_u", "weeks_wf"), row.names = c(NA,10L), class = "data.frame")
```

this command works

```
y <- mutate(y, i = ifelse(!is.na(i), i, 0))
```

this loop does not

```
vars <- c("weeks_hd_e", "weeks_hd_u", "weeks_wf_e", "weeks_wf_u", "weeks_hd", "weeks_wf")
for (i in names(vars)) {
    y <- mutate(y, i = ifelse(!is.na(i), i, 0))
}
    
View(y)
```

Comment: `names(vars)` is referring to object names, which do not exist in `vars` as you've given to us in the loop example. 

Does for `(i in vars){etc}` fix your issue?

Comment: hmm...no, unfortunately, that does not make any difference

Answer (score 0):

i have been given two excellent answers from friends:

```
for (i in 1:length(vars)){
    y[vars[i]][is.na(y[vars[i]])] <- 0
}
```

or

```
y[, vars] <- apply(y[, vars], 2, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))
```

Comment: Without loops, are you wanting to turn all columns except for the first two to 0 if they are NA? `y[-(1:2)][is.na(y[-(1:2)])] <- 0`

Answer (score 0):

The `replace_na` command from the tidyr package does exactly what you want.
Use it like this:

```
install.packages("tidyr")
library(tidyr)

# your data
y <- structure(list(pid = c(1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L,1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L), year = 1968:1977, weeks_hd_e = c(3,0, 50, 49, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 49), weeks_wf_e = c(4, 6, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), weeks_hd_u = c(NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0), weeks_hd = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), weeks_wf_u = c(NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA), weeks_wf = c(NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_)), .Names = c("pid", "year", "weeks_hd_e", "weeks_wf_e","weeks_hd_u", "weeks_hd", "weeks_wf_u", "weeks_wf"), row.names = c(NA,10L), class = "data.frame")

# replacing NAs in your dataframe
# specify the variables you want to replace NAs in and the replacement in the `replace` = list argument
y <- replace_na(y, replace = list(weeks_hd_e = 0, weeks_hd_u = 0, weeks_wf_e = 0, weeks_wf_u = 0, weeks_hd = 0, weeks_wf = 0))
```

Note that this meets your preference to specify the variables by name and is more flexible in terms of replacement, i.e. you can replace NAs in numeric and character variables in the same command.